# Какой метод,принимает TextView и передает его,на вторую Аctivity,при нажатии на Button,в Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout

     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="16dp"
     android:paddingLeft="16dp"
     android:paddingRight="16dp"
     android:paddingTop="16dp"
     tools:context=".CreateMessageActivity">

    <Button
         android:id="@+id/send"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText2"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
         android:text="@string/gonder" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/message"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
         android:ems="10"
         android:inputType="" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
         android:text="@string/ad1" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/message"
         android:layout_alignStart="@+id/message"
         android:layout_below="@+id/message"
         android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
         android:ems="10"
         android:inputType="textPersonName"
         android:text="@string/ikinciedit" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/message"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
         android:text="@string/ad2" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: любой метод, который вы напишите сами, в API Android такого метода нет. Чтобы получить помощь, опишите свою проблему подробнее, чтобы и другим было понятно, в чем именно ваша проблема.

Comment: Мне надо, при нажатии на Button, текст передался на вторую Activity